# QGIS expressions function not loading when opening composer

Tags: pyqgis

I created a function to display the coordinate system of a map and transformation parameters etc. When I open the composer, I have to go to functions and press on load button to re-load my function to make it work. Otherwise, I get an error as follows:

Eval Error:
global name 'qgis' is not defined

Code is as follows:

```
"""
Define new functions using @qgsfunction. feature and parent must always be the
last args. Use args=-1 to pass a list of values as arguments
"""
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
import re

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def test5(feature, parent):
    canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
    crsname = canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs().description()
    return crsname
```

I am using 2.18.14 of QGIS. As soon as I hit the load button, the code starts working but I want to make sure it auto-loads on startup.

Comment: Most welcome, glad it helped! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either:

1. Import the `qgis` module at the beginning:

   ```
   import qgis
   ```

---

2. Or replace `canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()` with:

   ```
   canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
   ```